# Angular - Select control not reacting to changes

Tags: angular, select, time, drop-down-menu, angular11

I have a select input that should display time values in steps of 15 minutes, but somehow I can't select any value. here is the code:

```
<select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="selectedTime" >                
    <option *ngFor="let time of getAvailableTimeValues()" [ngValue]="time|date:'shortTime'">{{time | date:'shortTime'}}</option>
</select>
```

The selectedTime model is a string in this case. I have tried several variations of this, with the same result. Is has to be a native select control because else the browser crashes for that many values. When I use the (change) event, it always shows the default initial value instead of the value being selected.

I know there are different controls for selecting a time, but they don't allow to block arbitrary intervals.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hello try the following code

```
<select matNativeControl [(value)]="selectedTime" >                
    <option *ngFor="let time of getAvailableTimeValues()" [ngValue]="time|date:'shortTime'">{{time | date:'shortTime'}}</option>
</select>
```

value directive works fine with `<mat-select></mat-select>`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the type of values being returned by the `getAvailableTimeValues()` method.

Your code will select a value if you return an array with the same strings or a named array but will not if you return an anonymous array of objects.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'select-form-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-form-example.html'
})
export class SelectFormExample {

  selectedTime: string;
  timeValues: any[] = [new Date(1621286945378), new Date()];

  getAvailableTimeValues() {
    /*This works since we are pointing to the same memory location via our variable and 
     the same values are drawn after each change detection cycle.*/
    return this.timeValues;

    /*This will work since strings are primitives. Again the same values are drawn 
     after each change detection cycle.*/
    //return [new Date(1621286945378).toISOString(), '1621287945379'];

    /*This will not work since Date is a reference type that changes on each change 
    detection cycle. The view is being re-drawn after each change detection cycle and
    we are losing the reference to the value we just clicked.*/
    //return [new Date(1621286945378), new Date()];
  }
}
```